# Missing character in BibTeX

Tags: fonts, bibtex

During compiling literature using BibTeX I've got the following message in the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (MiKTeX 2.8) 
(preloaded format=pdftex  010.12.7)  7 DEC 2010 00:33 entering extended mode
Missing character: There is no ę in font cmr10!
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the encoding of your `bib` file is utf-8 or some other encoding that BibTeX can not handle. BibTeX itself does only handle us-ascii properly, as far as I know, although it works fine unless no problematic characters occur. But without a working minimal example, your problem will be difficult to solve.

Answer (score 5):

You need to replace instances of that character in your bibtex file with: `\k{e}` and make sure that you have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in your preamble (in your main document). For information on other accents and how to do them in LaTeX see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Accents).

An alternative is to use [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and biber instead of bibtex as these tools can deal with more unusual characters directly...